# Using str_match on a field in data frame from rtweet

Tags: r, string-matching

I tried using `str_match` from `stringr` and it works on a simple test example.  But it doesn't work on data that comes back from [rtweet](https://github.com/mkearney/rtweet):

Here is a made-up data frame it does seem to work on:

```
test <- data.frame(c(1), c('something'))
names(test) <- c('value', 'item')

subset(test, !anyNA(str_match(item,'thing')))
```

That gives a match and doesn't filter the item out, producing:

```
  value      item
1     1 something
```

Changing it to something else:

```
subset(test, !anyNA(str_match(item,'thang')))
```

...filters the item out, as expected:

```
[1] value item 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

But the "mentions_screen_name" field in the data frame that comes back from rtweet doesn't seem to be able to be subsetted like this.  Other logic operations (like `mentions_screen_name == ...`) work for picking a column out.  But `!anyNA(str_match(mentions_screen_name, '...'))` won't work, even if you match on the exact text of the field.

I'd like to send the data which doesn't seem to be able to be selected by
str_match.  But the script that gets the data is using rtweet and
needs Twitter apps credentials.

The simple example like I said works, though.  Is there something different about the rtweet data?

Comment: `str_match` is used to extract the actual matches but I think you should be using `str_detect`; it returns a logical result if the pattern is in the string. That way you won't have to do `!anyNA` to see if there is a match or not.

Comment: @MattMills Is there any case where `str_detect(haystack, needle)` and `!anyNA(str_match(haystack, needle))` would give different results?  I'm not an R programmer but saw this case in person (and suggested asking StackOverflow).  Anyway, if you would take the `mentions_screen_name` field out via copy/paste and use it as the "haystack" it would work in an isolated call.  Yet somehow trying it as the logic for the `subset` operation did not, while a literal equality test for that string would.  :-/  What kind of sanity check might someone do in such a situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data structure for mentions, hashtags, etc is currently a character vector created by collapsing the values for each tweet into a single string separated by commas. The next version of rtweet will include some utility functions to make handling this structure a little easier. In the meantime, you can either convert mentions into a list object:

```
strsplit(mentions, ",")
```

Or use functions like grep/grepl to search for matches within strings.

I'm not totally sure this answers your question, so if I misunderstood you I'm sorry.